# Creating a source for content to be consumed by Feeds?

Tags: nodes, feeds

I'm creating a site that is to serve as a source for nodes for several 'client' sites. The plan is to have the client sites use Feeds to get the new and updated nodes from the source site. However I'm not sure how to have the source site actually make those nodes available in a format where feeds can get a hold of them.

These nodes have node references, fields, field collections, and also file and image fields, so all that data needs to go over to the client sites.

Is there a "go-to" module for this, or will I have to write my own functionality?